# Can you help me with this oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Return the employees with the least and most characters in their name (full name). If there are many, select only those that come first in alphabetical order.
Only two employees will therefore be returned. You will project their names. (full name), the size of their name, and the ASCII value of their name.

here is what i did :

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME ||' '|| LAST_NAME FULL_NAME ,
       (LENGTH(FIRST_NAME ||' '|| LAST_NAME)-1) Taille_caractere , 
       (ascii(FIRST_NAME ||' '|| LAST_NAME)-1)  Valeur_ASCII
  FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

but now i want to display two employees , the one with less character and the one with more character

Comment: Please post sample data to demonstrate the result

Comment: What is "the ASCII value" of a name?  You'll see from [the documentation for ASCII()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ASCII.html) that it only considers the first character of any string, e.g. for 'Ellen Abel' it returns 69, the code for 'E'. Then you subtract 1 to get 68. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can `row_number()` the rows twice and take the terminal cases

```
select Taille_caractere, Valeur_ASCII
from (
    SELECT FIRST_NAME ||' '|| LAST_NAME FULL_NAME ,
           (LENGTH(FIRST_NAME ||' '|| LAST_NAME)-1) Taille_caractere , 
           (ascii(FIRST_NAME ||' '|| LAST_NAME)-1)  Valeur_ASCII,
      row_number() over(order by LENGTH(FIRST_NAME ||' '|| LAST_NAME), FIRST_NAME ||' '|| LAST_NAME) rn1,
      row_number() over(order by LENGTH(FIRST_NAME ||' '|| LAST_NAME) DESC, FIRST_NAME ||' '|| LAST_NAME) rn2,
      FROM EMPLOYEES
) t
where rn1 = 1 or rn2 = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
WITH cteEmployees
  AS (SELECT FIRST_NAME,
             LAST_NAME,
             FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS FULL_NAME,
             LENGTH(FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME) AS FULL_NAME_LENGTH
        FROM EMPLOYEES),
  cteLeast AS
     (SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT *
                FROM cteEmployees
                ORDER BY FULL_NAME_LENGTH ASC,
                         LAST_NAME ASC,
                         FIRST_NAME ASC)
        WHERE ROWNUM = 1),
  cteMost AS
     (SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT *
                FROM cteEmployees
                ORDER BY FULL_NAME_LENGTH DESC,
                         LAST_NAME ASC,
                         FIRST_NAME ASC)
        WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
SELECT *
  FROM cteLeast
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM cteMost
```

The problem of determining the ASCII value of the name I leave to you since I don't understand what that means.